# ParametricPlot of multiple curves Plot y[z][t] versus x[z][t] with both change with t (continuous variable) and z (represent different groups)

Tags: plotting

Two functions both change with the same independent variable t, there is another variable represent different groups (z). how to plot y[t] versus x[t] with each group of z represented by one independent curve. See example equation below, with z as a separate integer variable that varies while t is a continuous variable. Please note I do not plan to use Manipulate function.

```
x[z_][t_] := z/5*Exp[-0.1*t]
y[z_][t_] := 500/(2 + x[t])
z={1,2,5,10,20}
ParametricPlot[{Evaluate[x[z][t]],Evaluate[y[z][t]},{x,0,100},{z,zlist},AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) within [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) to plot multiple curves.

There are a few issues with your code.  1) The definition of `y[z][t]` refers to `x[t]` not `x[z][t]`.  2) `zlist` isn't defined.  3) The syntax of `ParametricPlot` doesn't take anything like `{z, zlist}`.

This works:

```
x[z_][t_] := z/5*Exp[-0.1*t]
y[z_][t_] := 500/(2 + x[z][t])

ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[Table[{x[z][t], y[z][t]}, {z, {1, 2, 5, 10, 20}}]]
, {t, 0, 100}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

All the curves overlap, because they're all variants of `y = 500/(2 + x)`.

Comment: `Manipulate` can help to visualize the overlap: `Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[
  {{x[20][t], y[20][t]}, {x[z][t], y[z][t]}}, {t, 0, 100},
  PlotStyle -> {{LighterBlue, Dashed}, Red},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{20, z}, {.5, .5}],
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {80, 250}}],
 {z, zlist}]`

Comment: This Manipulate function is really helpful.  Thank you both.